# How can I click missed calls icon to open system Missed Calls UI?

Tags: android

I can use the following code to display a notification icon of missed calls, I hope to click the icon to open system Missed Calls UI, how can I do ? Thanks!

At present, I can open ui.CallerMain.class UI if I remove the comment.

BTW, in system Missed Calls UI, missed calls are listed in there.

```
  private void ShowMissCallNotification(Context myContext,String myContentText) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) myContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.sym_call_missed,
                                    myContext.getString(R.string.app_name), 
                                    System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; 

    CharSequence contentTitle= "Title"; 
    CharSequence contentText =myContentText; 

    //Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(myContext, ui.CallerMain.class); 
    //PendingIntent contentItent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0,  notificationIntent, 0);

    //notification.setLatestEventInfo(myContext, contentTitle, contentText,contentItent);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationID, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a Pending Intent to the notification which will trigger the Call History.

First create an intent with Call Log

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resultIntent.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Then obtain the PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
```

Then set the PendingIntent to your notification builder

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon()
.setContentTitle()
.setContentText()
.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Now clicking the notification will open the Call Log.

**Update:** The code commented out in your snippet will work if you create the Intent as mentioned above in this answer. But please be aware that the method by which you are creating notification has been deprecated. Use NotificationCompat class from the support library in future.